# Linq-to-SQL Predicate VS UNION

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have table `Order` and `OrderItem`. Now, I need to get all *order items* for a range of *orders* (For example, order for the entire month). The *order* and *order item* itself has many columns. So, using `Include("OrderItem")` is amazingly slow.

The number of record of *orders* is around 20K record per month with *order items* are around 50K-60K records.

Since it is a range of date (eg. daily, weekly, monthly, yearly, etc...) currently, I am doing 2 selects.

```
var orders = (from rec in Orders.AsNoTracking()
              where (rec.OrderDate >= startDate) && (rec.OrderDate <= endDate)
              orderby rec.OrderDate descending
              select rec).ToList();

var orderItems = (from rec in OrderItems.AsNoTracking()
                  join recOrder in Orders.AsNoTracking() on new { rec.LocationId, rec.StoreId, rec.OrderId } equals new { recOrder.LocationId, recOrder.StoreId, recOrder.OrderId }
                  orderby recOrder.OrderDate descending
                  where (recOrder.OrderDate >= startDate) && (recOrder.OrderDate <= endDate)
                  select rec).ToList();
```

This is all good. However, when I do paging (1 page can display 25 - 1000 records per page depending on user preferences), I am thinking to get away from 2 selects and use union or predicate (using PredicateBuilder in LinqKit), something like this:

```
var orders = (from rec in Orders.AsNoTracking()
              where (rec.OrderDate >= startDate) && (rec.OrderDate <= endDate)
              orderby rec.OrderDate descending
              select rec).Skip(page * recPerPage).Take(recPerPage).ToList();
```

Now, to get the *order items*, I propose to use 3 options. Please let me know which one is better for small records (25 - 1000 records per page).

Option #1: Use another select with *Skip* and *Take* for *order items*.

Option #2: Use Union.

```
IQueryable<OrderItem> queries = null;
foreach (Tuple<int, int, int> key in orderIds)
{
    int locationId = key.Item1, storeId = key.Item2, orderId = key.Item3;
    var recs = (from rec in OrderItems.AsNoTracking()
                where (rec.LocationId == locationId) && (rec.StoreId == storeId) && (rec.OrderId == orderId)
                select rec);
    queries = (queries == null) ? recs : queries.Union(recs);
}
var orderItems = queries.ToList();
```

Option #3: Use PredicateBuilder.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<OrderItem>();
foreach (Tuple<int, int, int> key in orderIds)
{
    int locationId = key.Item1, storeId = key.Item2, orderId = key.Item3;
    predicate = predicate.Or(rec => (rec.LocationId == locationId) && (rec.StoreId == storeId) && (rec.OrderId == orderId));
}
var orderItems = OrderItems.AsNoTracking().AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();
```

I prefer to use *Union* or *PredicateBuilder* so to get *order items* the function doesn't have to know if the orders were selected using Date Range **OR** search by product **OR** search by customer **OR** any other future search options. All **OrderItem** need to know is the list of order ids.

So, my question is, **in term of speed and performance**, which option is the best option?

> NOTE:
>
> If I tried to get 1000 records, sometimes Union and PredicateBuilder will throw StackOverflowException. So, I limit it to 500 records. If user preference is 1000 records, then, I do 2 calls.
>
> I also tried to use LINQPad to look at SQL generated by predicate builder, but it couldn't recognize `AsExpandable()` (Yes, I have included LinqKit DLL). So, no luck here.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this really LinqToSql? or EF6? or EF Core? All these are different.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It is actually EF6... I didn't know LinqToSql is different than linq-to-entities... My apology.

Comment: No problem. Updated the tags for you, will remove the comments shortly...

Comment: Don't remove the comment. It is good. It educates others. I learn something new today.

Comment: You're going to a lot of trouble to avoid Include. If the problem is the size of the data then could you not us Include and then select an anonymous type with the days that you need? To me this question feels like there is a problem with the index(es) joining the order and orderitem tables, that is preventing the Include from working well. Why three fields in the join, for example, why not just OrderId?

Comment: @sjb-sjb, I did not design the database. It is given to me. Those 3 fields are primary keys of Order table. There are millions of records and lots of connected tables. I don't think my boss will allow me to redesign the whole legacy database and the app. In regards to only selecting the fields, there are many different reports. Yes, I can do it, but mostly the fields are used. I've tried to use Includes, but selecting only 140K order records with about 360K order items record takes about 5 minutes (if not timed out). Using two selects (instead of Include) reduces the time to about 10 seconds.

Comment: Why wouldn't you select just the 25 - 1000 order records with 75 - 3000 order items?

Comment: @sjb-sjb that is because there are summary fields on top which required all records to be loaded. Anyway, that is not my question. My comment above to show how slow using Include in **large records**. My question is about Predicates VS Union on **small records** (ie. 25 - 1000 records) in term of **speed** and **performance**. Therefore, you are right in this instance about selecting small records. So, from your comment above, are you saying **Include** is faster and more efficient than using **Predicates** or **Union** when selecting **small** set of  records (ie. 25 - 1000 records)?

Comment: Well, I can't say that I have tested that specifically.  I think that the EF translation of Include should be as good as a handmade workaround... I would be surprised if it were much slower. What I would say though is your code will be a lot easier and more maintainable if you use the mechanisms built into EF and only use workarounds when the approach intended by the EF team is actually not working..